# On iOS, can you show a UIActionSheet from a modally presented UIViewController without it being dismissed?

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, uiactionsheet

**EDIT:** Turns out my view controller's superclass was doing the dismissal and I didn't realize it.

---

**Original Question**

The title pretty much says it all.

I am presenting a modal view controller and then I want to prompt the user with an action sheet to confirm the selection they made in that modal view controller before dismissing it. When I call `[myActionSheet showInView:anyView]` my modal view controller is dismissed *automatically through no action of my own*. (I tried showing it in the modal view, app's window, etc. but they all had the same effect.)

This is problematic because my presenting view controller needs to know information from the presented view controller to act on what the user chose to do. Ideally it would not dismiss the modal view, the modal view could be the `UIActionSheetDelegate` and decide what message to send back to the presenting view controller underneath based on the sheet selection.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: If you know the answer, you can answer you own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, turns out my view controller's superclass was doing the dismissal and I didn't realize it.